# Lava hound attack strategy for farming resources

Tags: clash-of-clans

During the Lava Hound event, Hounds are 1/10th of their usual price. I'm drawing a blank on attack strategies for looting (farming) using Hounds. I've tried 3 or 4 Hounds and the rest Balloons. If the defending CC has troops that shoot (which they often do since everyone knows about the event), the Hounds and Balloons are toast. I'm trying to add Wizards and Hogs (to draw out troops) to my army composition, but at this point it doesn't seem like I'm going to use the sale.

Any suggestions? Is there a resource where I can find attack strategies for the current troop on sale? I find having these events make the game a lot more fun, but using some troops is trickier than using others.

Comment: This is opinion-based, so i doubt anyone will even want to give an answer. Also, this site is only for Q&A, so if you want to get opinions, go to some forum or something like that.

Comment: Read a bit about lavaloonion and maybe try taking a dragon with you

Comment: @Quijibo [Aren't game strategy questions on topic?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @TimmyJim This makes me confused, as I have seen a very similar post, also to CoC, that was closed for just this reason

Comment: @Quijibo I think a lot of users forget that game strategy questions are on topic here.  I'm sure there have been times where even I have forgotten that.  To that extent, I feel there are also a number of users who feel that these questions just historically don't do well, and are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try lavaloonion strategy.

You can read more about it here:
http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_Strategies/TH9_Lavaloonion

To deal with cc troops you can take a dragon or wizards with you, either in cc or in your army and take minions in cc or army accordingly. To drag out the cc troops use a hog rider. Taking out cc troops is tricky depending upon the layout. You can kill cc troops using the dragon or wizards and your archer queen if needed.

Comment: Thanks, can't wait for the sale to come back. Hopefully by then I will upgraded its level.

Comment: @northerner you're welcome.. All the best..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering, I found this strategy worked well and resulted in some loot gain and at least 1 star:

- drop 2 lightening spells and quake spell on ad that is closest to middle of base
- drop 4 or 5 lava hounds to closest ad and drop rage spell once they are close to it
- have 9 wizards and your heroes and a hog rider to lure out and take care of clan castle troops
- right after dropping lava hounds, drop a lot of balloons in a line behind them (by a lot I mean fill the rest of your camp up after the other troops have been trained)
- have your clan castle full of wizards, valkry or archers that destroy buildings while the balloons and lava hounds go after defence

NOTE: this strategy won't get 3 stars and is best used on bases with lots of resources to begin with (over 300k in elixir and gold).

Also note this was when the lava hound sale was on and may not be worth it until it's on sale again.